# A "try" shell script

Tags: linux, shell, portability

So, the idea is to have a script that tries to run a command, and if the command fails it shows up any warnings/errors. My try:

```
$ cat try.sh
#! /bin/sh
tempfile=`tempfile 2>/dev/null` || tempfile=/tmp/temp$$
trap 'rm -f $tempfile >/dev/null 2>&1' 0
trap 'exit 2' 1 2 3 15

echo "$@"
if ! "$@" >$tempfile 2>&1; then
   cat $tempfile;
   false;
fi
```

Do you think that this script is ok (wrt portability and functionality)?

Comment: I personally would rewrite this in Python. I admire people who can whip out complex working programs with shell scripts, but I myself would not take that risk.

Comment: What does having a script execute a command get you that simply executing the command directly doesn't?

Comment: @Steve, presumably this would be part of a larger script, to suppress output when a command doesn't fail

Comment: My gut feel is that this won't work with complex quoted commands. I second lpthnc's sentiment about writing this in Python (or Perl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some changes I would make:

- Use `"$@"` as Steve Emmerson suggested
- Don't redirect stdout of `tempfile` to `/dev/null`; that's what you're trying to capture in the variable!
- Consider `mktemp`; it is more portable.
- Capture and exit with actual exit code of command, so information is not lost.

E.g., without error checks,

```
tempfile=`mktemp 2>/dev/null || echo /tmp/tempfile$$`
[ -w "$tempfile" ] || { echo "Can't make tempfile" >&2; exit 1; }
"$@" 2> $tempfile
rc=$?
case $rc in
  0) ;;
  *) cat "$tempfile" >&2 ;;
esac
rm -f "$tempfile"
exit $rc
```

Answer (score 1):

I would enclose the $@ in double quotes in the "if" statement in order to preserve word boundaries.